# CSS/Javascript based drop down menu. Issue with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some issue getting a menu to `.hide()` after clicking on an element.

```js
$(document).on("click", "div.dropdown", function() {
  $(this).find("ul").show(0, function() {
    $(this).find("li").click(function() {
      var a = $(this).html();
      $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-title p").html(a);
      $(this).parent().hide(); //Onclick won't hide the UL
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
  return false;
});
```

```css
div.dropdown {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

div.dropdown div.dropdown-title {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown div.dropdown-title p {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}

div.dropdown div.dropdown-title span {
  float: left;
}

div.dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  z-index: 1001;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.dropdown ul li {
  line-height: 32px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-title">
    <p>Sort By</p>
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
    <li>Option 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am attempting to get the dropdown menu (the `ul` element) to `.hide()` when you click on one of the `li` elements in the menu, as well as when you `mouseleave` from the `ul`. Right now, just the `mouseleave` portion works and not when you click on one of the `li` elements. I am unsure of what I am overlooking, so if you see any errors or issue please let me know.

[Here's the link to my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtf7j2hk/)

Comment: When you click `div.dropdown` you show the `ul` which is within the `div.dropdown`. When you click on a ul item in the menu it run both the code `$(this).parent().first().hide();` AND `$(this).find("ul").show(0, function() {` as clicking on the `ul` will fire the `div.dropdown` click handler. Hope that helps.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rtf7j2hk/2/) Press `F12` and view console output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When clicking on the li the event propagating to the ul, so what really happens that the click on the li closing the list but the 'click' on the ul opens it again, you can stop the event propagation

```
$(document).on("click", "div.dropdown", function() {
    $(this).find("ul").show(0, function() {
        $(this).find("li").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var a = $(this).html();
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-title p").html(a);
            $(this).parent().hide(); //Onclick won't hide the UL
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
   });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: More times than not, I always forgot to check if the event is propagating. Thank you for the help and point this out.

Comment: Quick question. If I add an alert to the click on the li element, and then go back and click on another item, it fires the alert multiple times. Why is that? I thought the stopPropagation would take care of that? https://jsfiddle.net/rtf7j2hk/4/

Comment: It appears that if I unbind the click event on the li it will not only stop the propagation, but also stop the alert from firing multiple times. Any downside to this? https://jsfiddle.net/rtf7j2hk/5/